# HttpWebRequest GetResponse No Such Method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, servlets

Busy working on Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows phone and is wanting to call a servlet that returns json from one of my classes.

I have the following method so far:

```
public Login(string userName, string password){

   string servletUrl = "http://172.12.5.35:8080/SomeService/login?u="+userName+"&p="+password;
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(servletUrl);
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

}
```

But for some reason I get an error right by the "`GetResponse()`" method call saying that there is no such method? Anybody has any ideas? I've looked around quite a bit and my code seems right to me?

Edited---------------------------

```
public Login(string userName, string password){

   string servletUrl = "http://172.12.5.35:8080/SomeService/login?u="+userName+"&p="+password;
   using(var client = (IDisposable)new WebClient(servletUrl))
   {
        string result = client.DownloadString(servletUrl);

   {

}
```

But it seems that there is no `DownloadString` method for WebClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 (and Silverlight in general) doesn't support synchronous IO. If you look at the [Silverlight API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you'll find the compiler is entirely right - there *isn't* a `GetResponse` method. You need to use the async [`BeginGetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method instead.

Alternatively, use `WebClient` which makes the async part somewhat simpler - and of course C# 5's async support will make asynchrony much easier in general.

EDIT: As noted in comments - `DownloadString` is still synchronous, so not supported in Silverlight. You want the async API, e.g. `DownloadStringAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon, I'm now doing it as follows (Please see edited post)... But I'm still getting errors...

Comment: @DeanGrobler **Reread** Jon's answer and try `DownloadStringAsync`